# Given E(x) check if u is an unbiased estimator

Tags: self-study, estimation

Given that ${E(X)=\frac{5\mu}{9}}$, check if ${\mu}$(hat)$=\frac{4}{7}x-1$ is an unbiased estimator

I am having trouble understanding this topic and I have no idea what to do with this. I have tried searching on how to solve this but I cant find a proper explanaion on how to solve this.

[edit]:

I know that I have to show that $E(X) = \mu$(hat),

$\frac{5\mu}{9}=\frac{4}{7}x-1$,

$35\mu = 36x - 63$

does this mean they are not equal?
but I have no way of telling that because they have different variables...

besides, how can ${E(X)=\frac{5\mu}{9}}$ when $E(X)$ is supposedly equal to $\mu$

Comment: I assume x is an observed value of the random variable X. To be unbiased the estimator $\mu$(hat) must have expected value equal to 5 $\mu$/9. So see if (4E(X)/7)-1 equals 5$\mu$/9.  Does it appear to be biased?

Comment: but how would I check if the values are equal if there are no variables that are common with each other?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I think E[mu(hat)] sbould be equal to mu inorder for it to be unbiased. Although it is not clear mu hat is an estimator of mu not E(X).

Comment: $\mu$(hat) was not defined in the statement of the problem. E(X) is a constant and $\mu$(hat) is a random variable. So $\mu$(hat) cannot be equal to $\mu$ which is a constant. Also x is the observed value of the random variable X. So you need to look at its expected value. Under the OPs interpretation 5$\mu$/9=$\mu$. which can only be true if $\mu$=0.. In that case  x  would always be 7/4. My interpretation says that $\mu$(hat) is biased.  The OPs leads to a contradiction since 0 does not equal -1.